# Is there a simple way to handle base 13 (or generic base N)?

Tags: vb.net

I can quickly knock together soem code to xlate base 10 to/from bae 13, but I just wondered if something very easy already exists in VB.NET (or even somethign generic, with base N, but right now I am only looking at base 13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing easy already exists in VB.NET.